# How do I solve this reduce/reduce conflict in Bison?

Tags: bison, ambiguity, reduce-reduce-conflict

Here is an excerpt from [filename].output
    state 94

```
   32 expr: expr . opt_at_type '.' TYPEID '(' opt_expr_list ')'
   39     | expr . '+' expr
   40     | expr . '-' expr
   41     | expr . '*' expr
   42     | expr . '/' expr
   42     | expr '/' expr .
   44     | expr . '<' expr
   45     | expr . LE expr
   46     | expr . '=' expr

    '@'  shift, and go to state 73

    '.'       reduce using rule 23 (opt_at_type)
    '.'       [reduce using rule 42 (expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 42 (expr)

    opt_at_type  go to state 74
```

opt_at_type is defined as:

```
    opt_at_type:
            { $$ = idtable.add_string("SELF_TYPE"); }
            |       '@' TYPEID
            { $$ = $2;   }
            ;
```

and can you enlighten me why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that yacc precedence levels are only taken into account to resolve shift/reduce conflicts, not reduce/reduce.  In this case, the `opt_at_type` rule can match an empty string (it's optional), leading to a reduce/reduce conflict.

To fix it, you need to unfactor the rule to get rid of the epsilon production:

```
expr: expr '.' TYPEID '(' opt_expr_list ')'
    | expr '@' TYPEID '.' TYPEID '(' opt_expr_list ')'
    | expr '+' expr
       :
```

Without the epsilon production, it doesn't need an early reduce, so the conflict becomes a shift/reduce conflict which can be solved by yacc precedence normally.

Answer (score 0):

When Bison sees the following:

```
expr '/' expr '.'
```

It doesn't know if this equates to:

```
1) expr opt_at_type '.'
```

OR

```
2) expr '/' expr opt_at_type '.'
```

For 1) it would reduce `expr '/' expr` to `expr` first and for 2) it would reduce /* Empty */ to `opt_at_type` first.

So we have discovered the ambiguity, to solve it you must determine what syntax you want.  One solution would be to make the first expr rule a separate rule so that it could not be used inside the other expressions like so:

```
typeexpr: expr opt_at_type '.' TYPEID '(' opt_expr_list ')'
```